Get user requested URL (valid/invalid) in ColdFusion
I am trying to make a custom router. For this I am trying to grab the user requested URL from the application.cfc. The problem is when a invalid directory or URL is received lucee directly throwing 404 error. I just want to get the requested URL and bypass this 404 error. Moreover, after grabbing the URL I want to manually handle the user request.

Please [edit] your question to include your code attempt.

Perhaps you could test the url with a cfhttp call and check its results before relocating hte user.

The problem has been solved. Basically, you have to send each request through index.cfm. So, if you pass an url like localhost:8888/index.cfm/hello/wow you will not encounter an error and the requested url can be fetched using CGI.REQUEST_URL (e.g. /hello/wow).
Moreover, if you want to remove index.cfm marker you have to enable URL rewrite. Then the url (localhost:8888/hello/wow) will work without throwing any error.
For URL rewrite refer to these,

How to implement urlrewrite in lucee

https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/routing/requirements/rewrite-rules



In your Application.cfc, employ the onMissingTemplate() function which will execute when a template is not found.  You can put your custom code handling in there.
More info:
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/application-cfc-reference/onmissingtemplate.html

Yes but that only grabs *.cfm files if they are missing. My problem is with the url, for example if I have an url localhost:8888/hello (hello doesn't exist as a directory) that time I am unable to get that user requested url from the Application.cfc. It seems like control is not returning to Application.cfc.
